# Computing the first Chern class of a manifold from the metric

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm a physicist, and I've been tasked with computing the first Chern class of the tangent bundle of a manifold endowed with a metric,

$$ds^2= f(x)^2 (dt^2+dx^2)$$

To do this, I define an orthonormal basis,

$$e^t=f(x)\, dt\quad e^x = f(x) \, dx$$

such that $ds^2 = e^a e^b \delta_{ab}$. Clearly $de^x = 0$, and $de^t = -(f'/f^2 )\, e^t \wedge e^x$ which using the Cartan equation, we can use to deduce the non-vanishing connection component,

$$\omega^t_x = \frac{f'}{f^2}e^t = \frac{f'}{f} dt$$

The curvature 2-form is simply $R=d\omega + \omega \wedge \omega$; the only non vanishing component is,

$$R^t_x = d\omega^t_x = \left( \frac{f''f-f'^2}{f^4} \right)e^x \wedge e^t$$

I guess $R^x_t = -R^t_x$? So, my first Chern class is defined as,

$$c_1(TM) = \frac{i}{2\pi}\mathrm{tr}(R) = 0$$

since the diagonal elements $R^t_t, R^x_x$ vanish. Would this be correct? It seems all too easy.

Comment: The curvature two form for a line bundle is $-dd^{c}\log(|s|_{\rho}^2)$. In particular, $d\omega+\omega\wedge \omega=d\omega$ in the case of the line bundle.

Answer (score 2):

You need a complex line bundle (standardly with a hermitian metric) in order to compute Chern classes. In your case, $c_1(TM)$ is going to be closely related to the curvature 2-form of the associated Riemannian metric. And, no, in general, the first Chern form (class) of a Riemann surface is not $0$.